# Having an issue with image overlapping

Tags: swiftui

I have an issue where my code is rendering first image `OG Image` in the left corner, and a few seconds my code fetches another image `User Image` and it gets replaced in the same position where the first image is. My goal was to render it right next to it and have it aligned with the horizon. Is the reason for it because it's in the same Hstack?

[image]
[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var urlInput: String = ""
    @ObservedObject var webViewStore = WebViewStore()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            HStack {
                // OG Image
                if let uiImage = webViewStore.fetchedUIImage {
                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
                
                // User Image
                if let userProfileImage = webViewStore.fetchedProfileUIImage { // Direct access should work
                    Image(uiImage: userProfileImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                }
                
               
                
            }
            
            if let videoURL = webViewStore.fetchedVideoURL {
                Text(videoURL.absoluteString)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
            }

            Spacer()
            Divider()

            HStack {
                TextField("Enter URL", text: $urlInput)
                    .padding()
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                Button("Load") {
                    if let validURL = URL(string: urlInput) {
                        webViewStore.loadURL(url: validURL)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: It is best to use `@StateObject var webViewStore = WebViewStore()`.
 Are the `fetchedUIImage` etc... functions or computed properties that rely
 on asynchronous fetching functions?
Note your code seems to work for me in my tests, the images are displayed side-by-side. Could you show the code for `WebViewStore`

Comment: certainly, I added the other part of the code, Thank you for your help @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: it seems that in your `private func loadImage(...)`
 you always assign the resutls to `fetchedUIImage`

Comment: I don't know how you caught it but it works now, so thank you I really appreciate it